# Jquery make toggle and replace multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i don't know how to fix this issues
i have a list of filed that will be visible when i click on edit button and disappear when i click on save 
**the probleme is how can i make it dynamic with all my field without retype the jquery code for all field** 
Here is my code

thanks a lot :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#name-text, #name-btn-edit").hover(function() {
    $("#name-btn-edit").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function() {
    $("#name-btn-edit").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });

  $('#name-btn-edit, #name-btn-ok').on(
    'click',
    function() {
      $('#name-btn-edit, #name-btn-ok').toggle();
      $('#name-text, #name-field').toggle();
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">

      <div class="form-control" id="name-text">Tony hawk</div>

      <span class="input-group-btn" id="name-btn-edit" style="visibility: hidden">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button></span>

      <input type="text" value="tony hawk" class="form-control" id="name-field" style="display: none">

      <span class="input-group-btn" id="name-btn-ok" style="display: none">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
                                    </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'all your fields'?  What fields are going to repeat?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you want to show multiple input boxes when you click "edit", use classnames rather than ids. Then in code just use the classname.

Comment: If you mean that the edit button is appearing when it shouldn't, you can look at the area that the tony hawk name field covers by adding a border, it goes all the way to the right side of the screen, so when you hover over there, you can see the edit pop up. https://jsfiddle.net/szekmjtv/ this is what I mean, please specify your exact question so we can understand how to help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the `id` attribute into a class, like this:

```
<div class="form-control name-text">Tony hawk</div>
```

Then, change your jQuery to look for `class` instead of `id`, like this:

```
$(".name-text, .name-btn-edit").hover(function () {
```

Also, keep in mind, since you're using classes, querying for a class can return multiple results, so you might use `closest` to find the parent of them and then trigger the specific search, like this:

```
$(this).closest(".input-group").find(".name-btn-edit").css("visibility", "visible");
```

This would be the working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".name-text, .name-btn-edit").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest(".input-group").find(".name-btn-edit").css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest(".input-group").find(".name-btn-edit").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    $('.name-btn-edit, .name-btn-ok').on(
        'click',
        function () {
            $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.name-btn-edit, .name-btn-ok').toggle();
            $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.name-text, .name-field').toggle();
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-control name-text">Tony hawk</div>
            <span class="input-group-btn name-btn-edit" style="visibility:hidden">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    Edit
                </button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" value="tony hawk" class="form-control name-field" style="display:none">
            <span class="input-group-btn name-btn-ok" style="display: none">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    Save
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/8fbt8aae/